# userModel.lastUser contains empty string

Tags: qt, qml, kde-plasma

I'm creating my own SDDM theme. During development, I noticed that userModel.lastUser contains an empty string in test mode. I checked on other SDDM themes - the same thing. In normal mode everything is ok. How can I fix this?

Did everything in accordance with the official documentation: https://github.com/sddm/sddm/wiki/Theming

Fragment of my code:

```
Item {
    id: root

    signal selected(var userName)

    property string userName: userModel.lastUser
    property string currentIconPath: usersList.currentItem.iconPath
    property string currentUserName: usersList.currentItem.userName

    ListView {
        id: usersList

        model: userModel
        delegate: Text {
            id: userItem
            visible: false
            text: model.name

            function select() {
                selected(name)
                usersList.currentIndex = index
                currentIconPath = icon
                currentUserName = name
            }

            Component.onCompleted: {
                if (name === userModel.lastUser) {
                    userItem.select()
                }
                console.log(userModel.lastUser)
                //userItem.select()
            }
        }
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Can you show us what `userModel` is? It is not clear what `userModel.lastUser` is supposed to mean. Your example doesn't entirely fit a `ListModel`?

Comment: See docs link in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the following small tweaks to your application:

- I eliminated `lastUser` - I couldn't find meaning in this property
- I update `currentUserName` and `currentIconPath` when it is selected, this part I kept
- I rewrote the selection to be based on reading and writing `currentIndex`. The advantage of using `currentIndex`, is the `ListView` control has built-in support for `Key_Up` and `Key_Down` key presses as long as the `ListView` control is the current focused control
- I introduced an onClicked handler so that the `currentIndex` gets updated and that the keyboard focus is reasserted
- It wasn't clear why your delegate was an invisible `Text`, I replaced it with `Frame` with an `ItemDelegate` because I can (1) supply an icon, (2) change the color
- I rewrote `Component.onCompleted` to initialize `currentIndex` to the last item in the list model because it appears that there appears to be a need to initialize focus on the last item. The `Component.onCompleted` was moved from the delegate to the `ListView`. This is because when it was on the delegate it would have fired *EVERY* time the delegate got rendered. Imagine the impact of this when you were to scroll through long list. The last visible item isn't necessarily the last item on the list

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    signal selected()
    property alias currentIndex: usersList.currentIndex
    property var currentUser: currentIndex >= 0 && currentIndex < userModel.count ? userModel.get(currentIndex) : null
    property string currentIconPath: currentUser ? currentUser.iconPath : ""
    property string currentUserName: currentUser ? currentUser.userName : ""
    ListView {
        id: usersList
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: userModel
        delegate: Frame {
            width: ListView.view.width
            property bool isCurrentItem: ListView.isCurrentItem
            background: Rectangle {
                color: isCurrentItem ? "steelblue" : "#eee"
                border.color: "grey"
            }
            ItemDelegate {
                id: userItem
                width: parent.width
                icon.source: model.iconPath
                icon.color: isCurrentItem ? "white" : "grey"
                palette.text: isCurrentItem ? "white" : "black"
                text: model.userName
                onClicked: {
                    usersList.currentIndex = index;
                    usersList.forceActiveFocus();
                    selected();
                }
            }
        }
        Component.onCompleted: currentIndex = model.count - 1
    }

    ListModel {
        id: userModel
        ListElement { userName: "Bill Gates"; iconPath: "smile-32.svg" }
        ListElement { userName: "Steve Jobs"; iconPath: "user-32.svg" }
        ListElement { userName: "Jeff Bezos"; iconPath: "smile-32.svg" }
    }

    footer: Frame {
        Text {
            text: "currentIndex: " + currentIndex + " currentUserName: " + JSON.stringify(currentUserName) + " currentIconPath: " + JSON.stringify(currentIconPath) + " "
        }
    }
}

//smile-32.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><path d="M16 29.8A13.8 13.8 0 1 1 29.8 16 13.815 13.815 0 0 1 16 29.8zm0-26.6A12.8 12.8 0 1 0 28.8 16 12.815 12.815 0 0 0 16 3.2zm-4.5 10.6a1.2 1.2 0 0 0 .608-.168 1.52 1.52 0 0 0 .464-.43 1.927 1.927 0 0 0 .278-.572 2.234 2.234 0 0 0 0-1.26 1.927 1.927 0 0 0-.278-.571 1.52 1.52 0 0 0-.464-.431 1.185 1.185 0 0 0-1.216 0 1.52 1.52 0 0 0-.464.43 1.927 1.927 0 0 0-.277.572 2.234 2.234 0 0 0 0 1.26 1.927 1.927 0 0 0 .277.571 1.52 1.52 0 0 0 .464.431 1.2 1.2 0 0 0 .608.168zm9.608-.168a1.52 1.52 0 0 0 .464-.43 1.927 1.927 0 0 0 .278-.572 2.234 2.234 0 0 0 0-1.26 1.927 1.927 0 0 0-.278-.571 1.52 1.52 0 0 0-.464-.431 1.185 1.185 0 0 0-1.216 0 1.52 1.52 0 0 0-.464.43 1.927 1.927 0 0 0-.277.572 2.234 2.234 0 0 0 0 1.26 1.927 1.927 0 0 0 .277.571 1.52 1.52 0 0 0 .464.431 1.185 1.185 0 0 0 1.216 0zm3.223 5.743l-.926-.379a7.863 7.863 0 0 1-7.39 4.976.166.166 0 0 0-.032 0 7.863 7.863 0 0 1-7.388-4.976l-.926.379a8.846 8.846 0 0 0 8.313 5.597.21.21 0 0 0 .035 0 8.848 8.848 0 0 0 8.314-5.597z"/><path fill="none" d="M0 0h32v32H0z"/></svg>

//user-32.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><path d="M19.5 15h-7A6.508 6.508 0 0 0 6 21.5V29h20v-7.5a6.508 6.508 0 0 0-6.5-6.5zM25 28H7v-6.5a5.506 5.506 0 0 1 5.5-5.5h7a5.506 5.506 0 0 1 5.5 5.5zm-9-14.2A5.8 5.8 0 1 0 10.2 8a5.806 5.806 0 0 0 5.8 5.8zm0-10.633A4.833 4.833 0 1 1 11.167 8 4.839 4.839 0 0 1 16 3.167z"/><path fill="none" d="M0 0h32v32H0z"/></svg>
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)